# Is there solution to this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My Code in Flask

```
    print('Image List= ', imgNameList)
    print('App_version= ', App_Version)
    print('Provider_Name= ', Provider_Name)
    print('Order_ID= ', Order_ID)
    print('Unique_Device_ID= ', Unique_Device_ID)
    print('Visit_ID= ', Visit_ID)
    App_Version_Flag = 0
    if App_Version is not None:
        App_Version_Flag = 1
    print('App_version_Flag= ', App_Version_Flag)
    response="success"
if response == "success": # The image was fetched successfullyfinal_Result = result
    filenameArr = imgNameList.split('|')
    for i in range(len(filenameArr)):
        filenameArr[i] = Provider_Name + '/' + Order_ID + '/' + Visit_ID + '/' + 
        filenameArr[i]

        save_folder=os.path.join(SAVE_IMG_FOLDER,Order_ID)
        os.mkdir(save_folder)
```

Tried all the possible ways to solve it but It does not. Script runs in AWS EC2 Instance

Comment: Do you have a traceback or know what variable is causing it? Some value you get is `None`.

Comment: Possible error from this line of code `filenameArr[i] = Provider_Name + '/' + Order_ID + '/' + Visit_ID + '/' + filenameArr[i]` any one of the variable having `None` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building a string concatenating vars, but one of them is not a string, it is `None` instead.
My guess is that the error happens in this line (next time add the full stack trace please):

```
filenameArr[i] = Provider_Name + '/' + Order_ID + '/' + Visit_ID + '/' + 
filenameArr[i]
```

It my guess is correct then one between `filenameArr[i]`, `Provider_Name`, `Order_ID` and `Visit_ID` is `None`. So you have to handle this case.

*A suggestion not related to this problem: checkout the `pathlib` module to build paths easier: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html*